# draw shape follow sketch

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, draw

Hi is it possible make something like this:
[Basic shape to window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNJM3.png)

In C# UWP app
I have class "Profiles" with dimensions of profile. User will draw basic shape and add profile

Comment: Are you searching for this:- http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/09/04/easy-drawing-and-inking-by-new-inkcanvas-control-for-universal-windows-app?

Comment: yes but no luck. i dont have idea what else to search